# Firebase search by php

Tags: php, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

my code:

```
$fetchData = $database->getReference('userInfo')->orderByChild('name')->equalTo('Abc')->getValue();
```

error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException: Client error: `GET https://androidapp-5c3c1-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/userInfo?orderBy=%22name%22&equalTo=%22abc%22` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response: in C:\xampp\htdocs\Firebase\PHP\includes\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Exception\RequestException.php:113 Stack trace: #0
C:\xampp\htdocs\Firebase\PHP\includes\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Middleware.php(69): 
GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException::create(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response), NULL, Array, NULL) #1 
C:\xampp\htdocs\Firebase\PHP\includes\vendor\guzzlehttp\promises\src\Promise.php(204): GuzzleHttp\Middleware::GuzzleHttp\{closure}(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response)) #2 
C:\xampp\htdocs\Firebase\PHP\includes\vendor\guzzlehttp\promises\src\Promise.php(153): GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise::callHandler(1, Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response), NULL) #3 
C:\xampp\htdocs\Firebase\PHP\includes\vendor\guzzlehttp\promises\src\TaskQueue.php(48): GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise::GuzzleHttp\Pro in C:\xampp\htdocs\Firebase\PHP\includes\vendor\kreait\firebase-php\src\Firebase\Database\Query.php on line 70
```

Comment: Please show what the expected output or result is?

Comment: Have you checked the relevant documentation associated with PHP.. 
1. Order by usually follows the where clause
2. what library are you using to connect to firebase.

400 error code is indicative that the request was not properly formatted (from the servers perspective).

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using [kreait/firebase-php](https://github.com/kreait/firebase-php/) (version 4.x or 5.x). The most likely reason why you are receiving this error is that the `name` field is not indexed in your Realtime Database.

You can add the index by adding the following configuration to [your project's database rules](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/_/rules):

```json
{
    "userInfo": {
        ".indexOn": "name"
    }
}
```

You can read more about indices on the Firebase Realtime Database in the official documentation at ["Index your database"](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data) and in the context of the PHP SDK in the [Realtime Database chapter of its documentation](https://firebase-php.readthedocs.io/en/latest/realtime-database.html).

In general, every time you encounter an `Uncaught ...` error, you usually can get more helpful information by wrapping the code causing the error in a try/catch block:

```php
try {
    // Performing an operation    
} catch {\Throwable $error} {
    // We caught an error
    echo $error->getMessage();
    exit; // This far, no further
}

// When we arrived here, everything worked as expected
```

Although PHP error handling is a general enough topic, it has been asked about so often in the context of the SDK that there's now an ["Error Handling" section in its documentation](https://firebase-php.readthedocs.io/en/latest/troubleshooting.html#error-handling).